# Solving an equation and Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon two exercises in a book I can not seem to solve. Hints and such very much appreciated.

The first is:
Has the following a solution $\left( x,y \right) \in \mathbb{Z}$:
\begin{equation}
2x^2 + 3y^2 = 24122017
\end{equation}

The second is:
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\psi(n)=\left\vert \left\{ a \in \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^* \left\vert a^{n-1}\neq 1 \right.\right\vert\right\}$, show that it holds: if $\psi(n)\geq 1 \Rightarrow \psi(n)\geq \dfrac{1}{2}\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Edit: For whatever reason I already asked the second question and answered it myself?! Can not remember that though, here is the link for anyone interested.
[Euler's Totient Function and a Subset of Z/nZ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546127/eulers-totient-function-and-a-subset-of-z-nz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for 1. problem:

If we take mod 3 we get $$2x^2\equiv 2x^2 + 3y^2  \equiv 24122017 \equiv 1$$

so $$ 2x^2\equiv 1$$

If we multipy this with 2 we get  $$4x^2 \equiv x^2 \equiv 2$$ and thus it has no solution.

Comment: Why does it suffice to show this just for mod $3$?

Comment: @Abbraxas - if the original equation had a solution, that solution would also generate a solution of the mod 3 equivalence. But $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$, so $-x^2 \equiv 2x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and thus $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$. John Watson just did the same thing without involving negatives. It is a matter of choice which you prefer. Since this equivalence has no solution, the original equation cannot have one either.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you!